# I found an error in the Xcode documentation about anchorPoint

Tags: xcode

[image: Xcode screenshot]

When I searched online for explanations of anchorPoint, iOS says that the (0,0) point of anchorPoint is at the top left corner, but the docs here say it's at the bottom left corner. Which one is correct?